# This is a pyqt5 app where I want to load a ui file based on option selected from combobox but the app crashes after it displays the ui file directly

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

The class that loads the ui file after the user selects option from combobox

```
class Ui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)
        self.show()
        self.exec_()
```

The widget class which displays the combobox and when an option is selected *selectionchange* is called to load the ui file

```
class Widget (QWidget):
    def selectionchange(self, i):
        if(i == 0):
            window = Ui()
```

The main

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("fusion")
w = Widget()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `QMainWindow` does not have a method `exec_`.

Comment: When it's removed nothing is displayed.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but as it is now, `window` is a local variable of `Widget.selectionchange`. If that is the only reference to your `Ui` instance it will get garbage collected when `Widget.selectionchange` returns. To get around this you need to create a persistent reference to your `Ui` instance for example by assigning it to an attribute of `Widget` (i.e. use `self.window = Ui()` instead of `window = Ui()`).

Comment: @Heike Thank you so much it worked.